# Jquery print preview not showing full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, printing

I'm using this tool to make a print preview of my page.

[Demo](http://etimbo.github.io/jquery-print-preview-plugin/example/index.html) [Plugin](https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin)

I have a table in my page. So when I draw preview after pageload, **it' not showing full page in Firefox**.

[image: Firefox]

But in chrome same page is working perfectly, showing a full preview.

Codes.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/joy/css/print.css') }}" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/joy/print/css/print-preview.css') }}" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/joy/css/print.css') }}" type="text/css" media="print"/>
```

This print.css is made by me.It's not from the plugin example.

```
$('body').printPreview();
$.printPreview.loadPrintPreview();
```

Am I missing something? How can I see the full preview in both firefox and chrome??

Comment: Demo looks good on FF in my machine. Can you share the link or fiddle that include your code.

Comment: Demo example contains the problem too(Downloaded one, not on net). At least on my machine it does. The copyright notice cuts into half at the end of page.@MilindAnantwar Though I got the solution. Problem was in iframe size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in **iFrame height**. If I adjust the iFrame height based on my total Page Height, it works correctly.

The Demo example also contain the problem in Firefox as of 10-02-14(Downloaded demo code). The footer or the copyright notice cuts into half in the print preview example.

So here is what I did. In the `jquery.print-preview,js` file, I replaced all instances of

```
print_frame.height($('body', print_frame.contents())[0].scrollHeight);
```

with

```
heights=Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height())+30;
print_frame.height(parseInt(heights));
```

This will set the iframe height with actual document height.